# How can i keep session alive in another web browser?

Tags: java, spring-security, jsessionid

I want keep my jsession in chrome alive for another browser, Is that possible? If yes, how can I do it?
I think of getting value of jsession and set for the new web browser I m using IE tab for solving applet problem in chrome.

Comment: This sounds like a `single sign-on` solution is required. Its not exactly one HTTP session that is to be shared across different environments, but the fact that someone is already logged in. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on .

Answer (score 0):

If you have no user mechanism at the page - you can't share session between different browsers. Because for your web-server they will look like different clients with same IP.

If you have some sort of authentification at that page, and you know which user is currently browsing it, you can put session identifier into user instance, and when user opens page in other browser, you ask him to log in. When he is logged in - you will set cookie with sessionId to new browser. This way session will be shared.

Comment: ok , and what i have to do if i want to log in chrome and after open web site IE without log in

Comment: Let's say you are user 'A'.
You have opened site in Chrome and logged in. Got some session for user stored on server, and session ID in cookies of browser set.
Then you have opened site in IE. No session id in cookies. You log in, on login success cookies with session ID is set.
This is the most secure way to share session between browsers.

Comment: ok, and i log in the web site after that i open IE for the same web page,but the authentification show cause jsession died or what

Comment: How do you imagine it should work?
You have opened page in chrome, then in IE and already logged in?

Comment: I know my question a little bizar, my real problem is that Chrome does not support applet anymore so i installed ie tab to solve the problem and when i used i have the problem to keep the session

Comment: If you want to receive a good answer and expect other developers to spend time thinking on your problem then try to spend time yourself formulating a question. Bye.